# How to call cross class functions in a KV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

@inclement So here is my updated code example.  For this rough example I want to using kv press a button under Generators class and call a function under the Clean class which clears the main_label and changes it to blank in preparation for the next use of the generator.

Here is the kv file

```
    BoxLayout:   # left side of App
        orientation: 'vertical'   #Orientation is Vertical instead of horizontal
     
        Button:
            text: 'Generic Generators'
            height: '50dp'
            size_hint: 0.20, None
            on_parent: drop1.dismiss()
            on_release: drop1.open(self)           
            
        DropDown:
            id: drop1
            on_select: btn.text = '{}'.format(args[2])   

            Button:
                text: 'LOUCHE'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 45
#               on_press: self.clear()
                on_release:  root.louche()
                on_release: drop1.dismiss()

        Label:              #Starter label in the center of the app that disappears when the generators are activated
            id: main_label
            text: "Press a random generator on the side and output will display here."
            font_size: 24
            size_hint_y: .95
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'top':.1}
```

Here is my python code:

````
#Builder allows us to call another file such as our kv file
from kivy.lang import Builder

#BoxLayout allows us to use this layout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

#Random allows us to use random choice and other random triggers
import random

#Allows us to trigger window size or make the app full screen
from kivy.core.window import Window

#Setting the size of the window that opens
Window.fullscreen = 'auto'

#Deciding if user can resize the window or not
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', True)  

class Generators(BoxLayout):
#Generates random LOUCHE choice for 7-9 rolls in Dungeon World  
    def louche(self, *args):
        LOUCHE = ('LOCALITY: Something specifically related to the current environment happens.\nThe buildings now on fire. The ground collapses. It\'s flooding. Moonquake!' , 'OFFER: Offer a bargain, an extra, or a perk for a cost.\noffer a better position, with risk. Offer a temptation.', 'UNEXPECTED DANGER: Make something up or roll it up at random.\nTie it in if you want now or worry about how it fits in later', 'CALLBACK: Use something that they\'ve given you. A backstory element.\nAn off-handed comment. Gear. A character sheet aspect', 'HARM: Deal damage', 'END SOMETHING: End an ongoing effect, bonus, or fictional advantage. Take a \nresource away, something you possess, whether it\'s a piece of gear, \nan ability, or an ally')
        self.ids.main_label.text = (str(random.choice(LOUCHE)))
 
class Clean():       
#Clears what is showing on the main_label of the application   
    def clear(self, *args):
        self.ids.main_label.text = ''

        
        
        
class app1(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('Experimental.kv')

if __name__=="__main__":
    app1().run()```
````

Comment: Post a minimal runnable example. It isn't clear to me that your error is related to the confusion you describe.

Comment: @inclement I apologize I have been very sick so I have not been able to produce a better example. I will try to do that this weekend and get it up for the communities approval.  Apologies for the bad first example I was worried id include too little to show my issue.

Comment: @inclement I have updated my example. Hopefully that provides more clarity on my question.